# Catch an SQL Exception with Spring Data JPA

Tags: java, spring, spring-data-jpa

The following methods tries to write data to DB (`firmRepository.save()`) and to ElasticSearch (`firmSearchRepository.save()`).

The problem is that I do not want to write to ES repository if the DB save failed. I am trying to catch the exception with `DataAccessException`, but through my tests I see that such exceptions as unique constraint violation -> get through and persistence in ElasticSearch still executes.

```
@Override
public FirmDTO save (FirmDTO firmDTO) {
    log.info("Database Request to save Firm: {}", firmDTO.getFirmId());
    Firm firm = firmMapper.firmDTOtoFirm(firmDTO);
    try {
        firm = firmRepository.save(firm);
        firmSearchRepository.save(firm);
        return firmMapper.firmToFirmDTO(firm);
    } catch (DataAccessException ex) {
        log.error(ex.getLocalizedMessage());
        return null;
    }
}
```

Is there way to catch those specific exceptions related to SQL?

Comment: Yes, but you can only be sure that something has been saved once a flush has been done, and the transaction has been committed. So that's where you should catch the exception (i.e. put a try block around the call to the method that starts the transaction, saves in database and commits the transaction).

Comment: @JBNizet and how do you do that with Spring Data JPA interface methods, like `.save()`?

Comment: Whether you use spring-data-jpa or not is irrelevant. You have a transactional method, and you need to save into ES after this transactional method call has succeeded and committed the transaction. Not inside that transactional method. Whether you use spring-data-jpa inside that transactional method or not is irrelevant.

Comment: @JBNizet You're misunderstanding the concept of spring-data-jpa.

Comment: Hmm, no, I'm not. But you're allowed to believe that if it makes you comfortable.

Comment: The issue here is that: unit of work is not clearly defined. As your original requirement, you should put all activities related to repository saving in an unit of work. After that execute ES saving activity. Then everyhing is clear and transactional

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Using the `saveAndFlush()` JPA repository method made catching Spring Data exceptions possible.

```
@Override
    @Transactional
    public FirmDTO save (FirmDTO firmDTO) {
        log.info("Database Request to save Firm: {}", firmDTO.getFirmId());
        Firm firm = firmMapper.firmDTOtoFirm(firmDTO);
        try {
            firm = firmRepository.saveAndFlush(firm);
            firmSearchRepository.save(firm);
            return firmMapper.firmToFirmDTO(firm);
        } catch (DataAccessException ex) {
            log.error("my exception");
            log.error(ex.getLocalizedMessage());
            return null;
        }
    }
```